# Python JSON header changed now getting Key Error [value] Not In Index

Tags: python, json, pandas

Apologies if I don't have everything laid out correctly for python folks. I'm working on fixing code I inherited in a language I don't work with often.

The structure of a json file that is regularly pulled for a program has changed causing our program to crash.

The relevant json used to look like this:

```
],"custom_variable_values" : [
     "1543788209",
     "Group",
     "Area",
     "Name",
     "00.000000",
     "-00.000000"
],
```

It now looks like this

```
,["1544479406","Group","Area","Name","00.000000","-00.0000000"],
```

The lack of name for the object seems to be ruining the script. How could I change the names of all the columns from 0-7 to the old names?

If it helps the python I'm trying to get running again is:

```
testdf = hosts['custom_variable_values']
series = pd.Series(testdf)
locdf = pd.DataFrame(item for item in series)
locales = locdf[[4,5]]
```

If I keep the above code in its previously working state I get the following error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/outagesAK.py", line 112, in <module>
  locales = locdf[[4,5]]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1963, in 
  __getitem__return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2007, in 
  _getitem_array
  indexer = self.ix._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1150, 
  in _convert_to_indexer
  raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
  KeyError: '[4 5] not in index'
```

It makes sense that it isn't in the index when I no longer have anything named 'custom_variable_values'

If I change the code so that it reads `testdf = hosts[6]` it executes without raising errors, but it doesn't pull the data it's supposed to at positions 4 and 5. It's not producing error codes at this point.

Update:

When I just try to re-name the column headers all of the values turn to NaN. Is this is an indexing issue?

What I did to change headers when making the dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['col1','col2','col3','etc'])
```

Update 2:

Was able to get the dataframe to have the correct column names by doing the following:

```
columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'etc']
df = pd.read_json(file) 
df.columns = columns
```

Update 3: Pulled my last stable version of the code added the code from Update 2 and everything runs now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code solved my problems. My columns in my original json file came pre-named. There was a change to the backend that changed how the json rendered out (why this happened is unclear)

I had to create a variable manually naming the column names and then apply it to the dataframe.

```
columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'etc']
df = pd.read_json(file) 
df.columns = columns
```

Comment: Update your question. Please do not post any update as an separate answer

Comment: This was literally the solution to my problem. My problem was that the column headers disappeared from the json causing nothing to index because I was requesting values that didn't exist. I created a variable with what I wanted the column names to be, loaded the json, then renamed all of the columns within the dataframe

Comment: This should definitely be an answer. @jfmc Not everyone thinks when they're reviewing; that's why it takes 5 to delete something.